# EACCES: permission denied with fs-extra only using nodemon

Tags: node.js, sudo, fs, nodemon, fs-extra

I am attempting to use the [move](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/move.md) method from the [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) npm module. It works for moving files and empty directories, but every time I try to move a non-empty directory while using [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/), I get this error:

```
[Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename 'path/to/src/dir' -> 'path/to/dest/dir'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'rename',
  path: 'path/to/src/dir',
  dest: 'path/to/dest/dir'
}
```

However, if I try to use the exact same method with good ol' fashioned `node index.js`, it works with flying colors. Why does nodemon not have sufficient permissions and how do I fix it?

## I have tried:

- Installing nodemon with sudo
- Installing nodemon without sudo
- Each of the first two but running nodemon with sudo
- Each of the first two but running nodemon without sudo

## EDIT:

Because of @Aw Snap's comment, I tried it on Mac OS and it seems to work even with nodemon.

I wonder if this is a problem specifically with the Windows Subsystem for Linux...

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows debian subsystem (wsl)

Comment: Maybe nodemon drops privileges calling node in your environment ? To verify add code to your app to create a file in a directory where everybody has access to. Then start your app and check the permissions of the created file.

Comment: Are you using powershell ?

Comment: absolutely YES. Windows is not a choice to develop modern apps. Also if you are developing a nodejs app, common environment is linux, no windows nor mac , so I advice to install linux. This distro is very good for developers like us https://elementary.io    In another way, could you upload a minimal version of your app maybe in github? This will help us to help you. Did you try in linux? If works in linux, nothing else should interest you

Comment: @Rupjyoti no, Windows Terminal: https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal

Comment: @mottek It is just my current User who owns it and there are full permissions on the file created. Note that even moving empty folders does work, it is just moving ones with files in them that gives the error.

Comment: @JRichardsz I will try and build a minimal version. I will also eventually try on Linux, but right now the question is addressing the problem in Windows SL, so the solution would have to fix it in Windows SL.